# file_get_contents does not work with protocolless urls?

Tags: php

Stuff like `//google.com` does not work with `file_get_contents` is there a solution that does not require adding the protocol to the string?

Comment: `file_get_contents` can fetch files too (it is what it does), therefore you MUST provide a protocol, else it will try to resolve it locally. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php . Also, it supports these protocols only: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use `file_get_contents` with `//google.com` because what it's actually doing is `file:///google.com` when you do this in your web browser it's actually using the current protocol you're currently on. So if you had `https://mywebsite.com` and you linked to something as `//google.com` it would actually do is `https://google.com`. That being said you need to do `file_get_contents('http://google.com');`

Comment: I am experiencing same problem right now and I am just curious if it matters if I prepend `http` or `https` when I want to fetch some content from `//cdn...`. Is it ok to use just `http` ?

Comment: @KamilLatosinski that would entirely depend on the cdn itself. If it accepts both http & https, then you can just use `//cdn...` in your html/js source, however if you're getting this server side you will need to explicit request either http or https, otherwise it'll default to file

Answer (score -1):

I think that providing protocol for loading resource with `file_get_contents` is necessary. This function is evaluated on server not on client browser where automatic protocol check with // works.

Why you cannot pass protocol?

If you still need to decide protocol based on actual request to server you can check the environment variable $_SERVER a if there is https put there https or vice verse.

Comment: You don't need to check if a request is http or https on the server. This is only relevant on the client to avoid the _"unsecure content"_ warning, which why you'd want to use a protocolless URL in the first place.

Comment: Sure you are right. But if you requirements are that you have to use file_get_contents and you need to create remote request based on protocol that your script was called than you need to use $_SERVER. I cannot image situation for this, but if this fit your requirements you can use it.